# SQL SERVER: Loading data all at ONCE or Checking ONE by ONE?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Which one could be a better practice? In my situation, I need to check if a specific data exists in a table. I am iterating through an *Excel* file and verifying if a code there exists in my table using *VB.NET*. I have two options to do this (*or if there is a better way to do this, I am open for suggestions*).

First is to check it one by one, this code is executed per loop:

```
SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1 WHERE Code = '" & codeFromExcel & "'"
rs = dbConn.Execute(SQL)

If Not rs.EOF Then
    isFound = True
Else
    isFound = False
End If
```

The other one is I load all the codes in a *List(Of T)*

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)()
rs = Nothing
rs = dbConn.Execute("Select Code from Table1")
If Not rs.EOF Then
     Do While Not rs.EOF
        myList.Add(rs.Fields("Code").Value.ToString)
        rs.MoveNext()
     Loop
End If
```

Then check every record if it is in the *List(Of T)* while iterating in the Excel.

```
If myList.Contains(codeFromExcel) Then
     isFound = True
Else
     isFound = False
End If
```

I've been working with this kind of stuff most of the time and I want to know which one is the most efficient way to use. At the moment I only have a few records in my database. I want my code to be ready and efficient when the time comes that I need to deal with numerous records. Thanks in advance!

Additional info: The data doesn't need to be "*fresh*" as that table is meant for one-time entry only.

Comment: How many records do you treat as *numerous*? Are we talking about 1K, 1M, 1B? Anyway a solid practice is to avoid the number of roundtrips between Application (Server) and Database. For filling your list (I would prefer HashSet) you can use a table direct with SqlDataReader which is a fast

Comment: What I mean of numerous is the _number of records in a table_.

Comment: I know but wich number is numerous? How many records do you expect in future in the table?

Comment: Okay, let's say 100k is more than enough for the requirement..

Comment: "cache" your DB codes one time in your app, and use that to compare. Like you are already doing in the 2nd code block. Having 100K round trip SQL queries is not going to be any where near usable.

Comment: I agree with @LouisvanTonder. 100K are too much for unique roundtrip but less enough for a good performance when loading all data once. Use a fast loookup data structure (HashSet, Dictionary), insert the values once on startup and work whith that data structure.

Comment: Actually, I think we are possibly misunderstanding you. How many records would there be the typical excel file? If the excel file has 10's or hundreds of records, it may be better to run 100 queries, than to cache 100K db records of which 99.9% wont be used....

Comment: the number of records in Excel is not fixed. It can be more or less. It can be 3 times the number of records in the table I am checking.

Comment: That's why I need to know which is the most efficient way to use since table and Excel is not fixed in terms of records.

Comment: Once you know whether there is or not a matching row, what do you want to do next with the excel row? If there is no matching row, do you want to insert the Excel row into the SQL Server table?

Comment: @JesúsLópez, I think that is going further out of the question. Regardless of what I'm gonna do with the Excel row, I want to know an efficient way of checking a record as stated above.

Comment: What about inserting the excel data into a temporal table using ' `SqlBulkInsert`? Once you have the data in SQL Server, you can query matching rows. But if the only thing you want to do is just knowing matching rows, the temporal table may not worth. However if you want to do additional processing, having the data in the temporal table allows you to perform set based operations. So, I don't think my question is a irrelevant one.

Comment: Thanks for the help/suggestions guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer to open as less connections to data base as possible.

So:

If the table is not very large (some hundred rows) I would go with the "cache" option.

---

Generally:
I would gather all excel codes in a list. ( excelCodes )

Then I would query something like `Select Distinct Code from Table1 Where Code In ( excelCodesList )` and store it in a second list ( foundCodes ).

Then I would compare these lists.

---

I test it on a table with **6.143.993** rows.

To select just one column (description) to "cache" took 1'29".

On the other hand query like:

`select distinct description from ItemDetail where description in ( 'abc','cddd','xxx' )`

took 0'58".

**UPDATE**
An index on `Code` column might help with performance.

Comment: Thanks! I think your approach is much better. Should give it a shot.